# background div is scrolling and menu pop up not scrolling when trying to scroll the menu on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have used ScrollIt.js for a one page scrolling website. When Clicking on menu icon a menu pop up will be open. But I can't scroll down the menu div to see the menus completely. When trying to scroll the menu the site will get scrolled.
If anyone have seen similar issue, Please share a solution.

```
<div id="main">
<header>
<ul id="menu">
<li>link 1</li>  
<li>link 2</li>    
<li>link 3</li>    
<li>link 4</li>    
<li>link 5</li>    
<li>link 6</li>    
<li>link 7</li> 
</ul>
</header>

    <div class="link-1-content"></div>
    <div class="link-2-content"></div>
    <div class="link-3-content"></div>
    <div class="link-4-content"></div>
    <div class="link-5-content"></div>
    <div class="link-6-content"></div>
    <div class="link-7-content"></div>

</div>
```

In iPhone Landscape I can see only upto link4.

Answer (score 0):

for ios you need to add a extra css

```
ul {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```